# C - wrong output when making a number comparative program

Tags: c

So I have this code where I make the user enter between how many numbers does thy want to make the comparation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
    int n;
    int x;
    int numbers[n];
    int count;

    printf("Mitme arvu vahel soovite võrdlust sooritada?: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Soovisite võrdlust teostada %d arvu vahel\n",n);
    printf("Sisestage palun arvud: \n");
    for (count = 1; count <= n; count++ ){
        printf("Arv %d:",count);
        scanf("%d",&numbers[n]);
        }
    for (count = 0; count <= n; count++){
        if (numbers[count] > x){
            x = numbers[count];
            }
        }
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
    }
```

Now the problem with it is that when the final printf is made, I get somesort of unrealistic number.

This is the output when I make the n 3:

```
./ComparingC Mitme arvu vahel soovite võrdlust sooritada?: 3
Soovisite võrdlust teostada 3 arvu vahel
Sisestage palun arvud: 
Arv 1:1
Arv 2:2
Arv 3:3
4196269
```

The number at the end is what I am talking about. It should show the biggest number amongst all of the other number but right now it showing something out of the deep space it seems.

EDIT:  Also when I make the n equal 5 and enter 1 as the first number, the program ends right there?

Comment: First initialize n and x variable before using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int n;
    int x = 0;
    int* numbers=NULL;
    int count;

    printf("Mitme arvu vahel soovite võrdlust sooritada?: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Soovisite võrdlust teostada %d arvu vahel\n",n);

    numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    if(numbers == NULL)
         return -1;

    printf("Sisestage palun arvud: \n");
    for (count = 0; count < n; count++ ){
        printf("Arv %d:",count+1);
        scanf("%d",&numbers[count]);
        }
    for (count = 0; count <= n; count++){
        if (numbers[count] > x){
            x = numbers[count];
            }
        }
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
    }
```

Just run it at your machine and find out your mistakes in your code and learn.

Answer (score 2):

You are completely skipping first element in your array!

```
 for (count = 1; count <= n; count++ ){
    scanf("%d",&numbers[n]);
```

Start from `0`th index and go till `n-1`

```
 for (count = 0; count < n; count++ ){
```

PS: value of `n` is to be initialized.

Comment: Fixed this. Wanted to use so that when it says please insert number x:  the first one would not be 0, but i made a new variable for it.

Comment: Nice catch there for `count <= n`, +1

Comment: @MadHatter yes.. elementary mistake. I have done it many times.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You declare `numbers[n]` without setting `n` to a sensible value. You can use variable-length arrays in C99, but your length is undefined which isn't a good idea.

Move the array declaration to after `n` has a proper value. And verify that the `scanf()` works before relying on the value.

Also, arrays in C are indexed from 0, so the loop is wrong too. It should be:

```
for (count = 0; count < n; ++count)
```

Further, the loop doesn't use `count`, it should be:

```
scanf("%d", &numbers[count]);
```

inside the loop, *not* `&numbers[n]` (which is an invalid out-of-bounds access that will invoke undefined behavior).

Comment: The "complete" answer... +1.

Comment: All things fixed but the final output is 194 no matter what and how many numbers I enter.

Answer (score 2):

**Error 1**: `n` is not initialized to proper value before declaring `numbers[n]`. `n` will be containing some garbage value.

**Error 2**: `x` is not initialized before using it in `if (numbers[count] > x)`.

I don't think I need to tell how to correct these logical errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are using variable length array (C99 feature). The value of `n` must be initialized before declaring VLA. 
Move your declaration

```
int numbers[n];
```

after inputting `n`, i.e, after the statement `scanf("%d",&n);`

```
 scanf("%d",&n);
 int numbers[n];
```